# Testing IE on Windows XP using Virtual PC, now that Microsoft's VHD images have expired

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-xp, virtual-machine

Wanting to test a site using IE on Windows XP, and was advised to use Microsoft Virtual PC. I was directed here for the Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

However for the Windows XP Image, the expiry date is February 14, 2013 and it is now unusable.

Are there any updated versions of this, or workarounds?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The VHD images can now be downloaded from http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

modern.ie is owned by microsoft so it's the official stuff.